# How does one override .Equals() for a Discriminated Union?

Tags: f#, overriding, equality, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union type and want to override `.Equals()`.

In this simple example I could have used the .Equals function for `int` to solve the problem, but in my code otherStuff does not support structural comparison.

The following code was my best try:

```
[<CustomEquality>]
type ModelArg = { Name: string; OtherStuff: int}
    with override this.Equals (o: obj) = this.Name = (o :?> ModelArg).Name
```

I then got a red squiggly line and the following message:

```
"The struct, record or union type 'ModelArg' has an explicit implementation of 'ObjectEquals'. Consider implementing a matching override for 'Object.GetHashCode'."
```

I would like to avoid doing that because I really only care for the field `Name` and also, for performance reasons.

Of course I could write an `equals` function but I would not be able to use it with `List` functions like `List.contains` and I need to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like a record type, not a discriminated union. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you that, since you're overriding the `Equals` method, it's a very good idea to override `GetHashCode` as well.

The reason for this is that in .NET in general (not just in F#), hash codes are often used as an approximation of equality. For example, if you were to put your objects in a hash table, the hash table would distribute them between buckets based on `GetHashCode`, and would look them up in the buckets that way too. Then, if `Equals` is implemented differently than `GetHashCode`, the hash table's behavior will be unpredictable - it might fail to look up an object that was just inserted or something similar.

Further, the error message does not suggest that you include the int in the definition of equality. All it says is that you need to implement `GetHashCode`, and do it in the same sense as your `Equals` implementation. There is also no performance penalty for doing this, as long as you never actually call `GetHashCode`. And if you do - see above.

Since all your `Equals` implementation does is compare the `Name` field, it would probably make sense to delegate `GetHashCode` to the same field as well:

```
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type ModelArg = { Name: string; OtherStuff: int}
    with 
       override this.Equals (o: obj) = this.Name = (o :?> ModelArg).Name
       override this.GetHashCode() = this.Name.GetHashCode()
```

Finally, your implementation of `Equals` would crash when called with a `null` or with an object of another type. I would suggest that you handle this case if you want your code to be robust:

```
       override this.Equals (o: obj) = 
           match o with 
           | :? ModelArg as ma -> this.Name = ma.Name
           | _ -> false
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but got a message: "The `CustomEquality` attribute must be used in conjunction with the `NoComparison` or `CustomComparison` attributes. I added the former and everything worked fine. I also modified your suggestion for handling the case in which the argument is of another type: I generate an exception in that case.

Comment: @Soldalma, I know this is an old thread, but I'd like to point out that generally, equality should never raise. Reason is that this can be used in non-generic, or generic-but-derived collections, where not all objects are of the same type. This would make such use case impossible.